# Can set and get invoked on ArrayList throw UnsupportedException

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist

In one of my recent code-reviews I was told that set/get are optional and might throw UnsupportedException.

This is my code:

```
 List<myObj> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

ArrayList doesn't identify get/set as optional. Moreover, in my understanding if I had used Array.asList() then I might have got these errors as Array.asList() wraps an array (fixed size) in the list interface.

So, my question is to please confirm if I'm correct and I will update my work if needed.

Comment: On `java.util.ArrayList`, no.

Comment: For `ArrayList`, no.  For other types, maybe.  (although rarely `get()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `java.util.List` interface ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)) defines some methods as optional; this includes `set(int, E)`, but *not* `get()`. The `ArrayList` implements both methods; they can be safely used. If the intent of the code reviewer is to have you wrap those calls in a try/catch block, I would vehemently disagree.

Comment: +1 for "vehemently disagree," so long as the `ArrayList` is created in the same method where you're calling `get` and `set`.  (If the `List` is getting passed in from elsewhere, my disagreement would be more moderate.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I completely agree. If you have code that accepts a `List` as input, you could still decide that it's the caller's fault to pass in an instance that doesn't support `set` and simply propagate the unsup exception, but you'd do well to document that. `Arrays.asList` in particular is a convenient shorthand in source code.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming by `UnsupportedException` you mean `UnsupportedOperationException`, most `List` implementations in Java extends `java.util.AbstractList`. This class has a few abstract methods of its own. The implementation for the methods like `set` and `get` are like so

```
public E set(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

In that sense, you don't have to implement them, they are optional. If you try to use them, you will get the Exception.

`java.util.ArrayList` overrides these methods, so there is no fear that such an Exception will be thrown.

`Array.asList()` return an instance of type `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` which also `extends AbstractList`, but overrides some of the methods, including `set` and `get`. They would not throw `UnsupportedOperationException` if you used the `List` interface.